# Where i am wrong using these reagents of lowrys protien estimation?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Reagent A : 2g Na2CO3 and 0.1N NaoH 
B :1% copper sulphate 
C : 2% sodium potassium tartarate 
Mixing them into 98:1:1 ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you found this method somewhere in the literature but it hasn't give full description of reagents used in Lowry Protein Assay, modified or not. For example, your reagent A should have been $\mathrm 2\%$ $\ce {Na2CO3}%$ in $\pu {0.10 N} \space \ce {NaOH}$ solution, according to Lowry's original paper (Reference [1]). Thus, for the benefits of future readers, I'd include here two updated protein assay methods suggested by RUF at Rice University, Houston, TX (Reference [2]). Their recommendations are as follows:

**Considerations for use of Hartree-Lowry or Modified Lowry Protein Assays**

The Lowry assay (see Reference [1]) is an often-cited and generally used protein assay since 1951 (claimed to be "The Most Highly Cited Paper in Publishing History"). For sometimes, it was the method of choice for accurate protein determination for cell fractions, chromatography fractions, enzyme preparations, etc. until the introduction of the Bicinchoninic Acid (BCA) Assay or "Smith Assay" in 1985 (Reference [3]). BCA Assay is based on the same principle, but can be done in one step, therefore it has been suggested  that the 2-step Lowry method is outdated (Reference [4]). However, the Lowry method has now been modified to be done entirely at room temperature. The Hartree version of the Lowry assay, a more recent modification that uses fewer reagents, improves the sensitivity with some proteins, and is less likely to be incompatible with some salt solutions. It provides a more linear response, and is also less likely to become saturated.

**Standard Procedure for Hartree-Lowry Protein Assays** ([Reference [5])

**Reagents:** **Reagent A** consists of $\pu {2 g}$ of sodium potassium tartrate tetrahydrate, $\pu {100 g}$ of $\ce {Na2CO3}$, $\pu {500 mL}$ of $\mathrm {1N}$  $\ce {NaOH}$, diluted to one liter with deionized water (final concentrations: $\mathrm {7mM}$ sodium potassium tartrate, $\mathrm {0.81M}$  $\ce {Na2CO3}$, & $\mathrm {0.5N}$  $\ce {NaOH}$). This can keep for 2 to 3 months.
**Reagent B** consists of $\pu {2 g}$ of sodium potassium tartrate tetrahydrate, $\pu {1 g}$ of $\ce {CuSO4.5H2O}$, $\pu {90 mL}$ of $\ce {H2O}$, $\pu {10 mL}$ of $\mathrm {1N}$ $\ce {NaOH}$ (final concentrations: $\mathrm {70mM}$ sodium potassium tartrate, $\mathrm {40mM}$ $\ce {CuSO4}$, & $\mathrm {0.1N}$  $\ce {NaOH}$). This can keep up to 2 to 3 months as well.
**Reagent C** consists of $\mathrm 1$ volume of Folin-Ciocalteau reagent diluted with $\mathrm 15$ volumes of ultrapure water.

**Assay:** First, as standards, prepare a series of dilutions of $\pu {0.3 mg/mL}$ bovine serum albumin (BSA) using the same buffer, which has been used to prepare solutions with protein-containing unknowns. Do the dilution to give concentrations of $\pu {30}$ to $\pu {150 \mu g/mL}$ ($\pu {0.03}$ to $\pu {0.15 mg/mL}$) of BSA in the buffer. 
Add $\pu {0.90 mL}$ of **Reagent A** to each test tube containing $\pu {1.0 mL}$ of each of your series of standards, your protein-containing unknowns, and buffer solution (for the reference). Then, vortex all test tubes to mix. Incubate the tubes for $\pu {10 min}$ in a $\pu {50~^oC}$ bath, then cool to room temperature.
Add $\pu {0.1 mL}$ **Reagent B** to each tube, vortex to mix, and incubate for $\pu {10 min}$ at room temperature.
Rapidly add $\pu {3 mL}$ of **Reagent C** to each tube, vortex to mix, incubate again for $\pu {10 min}$ in the $\pu {50~^oC}$ bath, and cool to room temperature. Final assay volume should be $\pu {5 mL}$. Now, measure absorbance at $\pu {650 nm}$ in glass or polystyrene cuvettes (pathlength: $\pu {1cm}$).

**Analysis:** Prepare a standard (calibration) curve of absorbance versus $\pu {\mu g}$s of protein (or *vice versa*) using BSA readings, and determine protein amounts in your unknowns from the curve. Then, you can determine concentrations of your original samples from the amount of protein determined, by applying all the factors including volume/sample, dilution, and other factors, if any.

**Procedure for Modified Lowry Protein Assays (room temperature)** ([Reference [6])

**Reagents:** Dissolve $\pu {20 g}$ of $\ce {Na2CO3}$ in $\pu {260 mL}$ of $\ce {H2O}$, $\pu {0.4 g}$ of $\ce {CuSO4.5H2O}$ in $\pu {20 mL}$ of $\ce {H2O}$, and $\pu {0.2 g}$ of sodium potassium tartrate in $\pu {20 mL}$ of $\ce {H2O}$. Mix all three solutions to prepare the copper reagent.
Prepare $\pu {100 mL}$ of a $\mathrm 1\%$ solution ($\pu {1 g}$ in $\pu {100 mL}$) of sodium dodecyl sulfate (SDS).
Also prepare a $\mathrm {1M}$ solution of $\ce {NaOH}$ ($\pu {4 g}$ of $\ce {NaOH}$ in $\pu {100 mL}$ of $\ce {H2O}$).
To make the $\mathrm {2\times}$ Lowry concentrate, mix $\mathrm {3}$ parts copper reagent with $\mathrm {1}$ part SDS and $\mathrm {1}$ part $\mathrm {1M}$ $\ce {NaOH}$. This final solution is stable for 2-3 weeks. Warm the solution to $\pu {50~^oC}$ if a white precipitate forms, but discard it if there is a black precipitate. It is better to keep the three stock solutions separately, and mix them just before use (recommended).
Prepare $\mathrm {0.2N}$ Folin reagent by mixing $\pu {10 mL}$ of $\mathrm {2N}$ Folin reagent with $\pu {90 mL}$ of ultrapure water. Kept $\mathrm {0.2N}$ Folin reagent in an amber bottle (the dilution is stable for several months).

**Assay:** Dilute protein-containing unknown samples with buffer to give concentrations from $\pu {0.025}$ to $\pu {0.25 mg/ml}$ if it can be estimated. If the concentration can't be estimated it is advisable to prepare a range of 2-3 dilutions spanning an order of magnitude. Prepare $\pu {200 \mu L}$ each dilution. Duplicate or triplicate samples are recommended.
Prepare a reference of $\pu {400 \mu L}$ buffer. Prepare standards for calibration curve using $\pu {0.25 mg/ml}$ bovine serum albumin (BSA) solution. Prepare concentration series of standards by adding BSA solution to $\pu{13 \times 100 mm}$ tubes (BSA volumes ranging from $\pu {40}$ to $\pu {400 \mu L}$) and bring up volume of each tube to $\pu {400 \mu L}$ by adding the appropriate amounts of buffer solution.
Now, add $\pu {400 \mu L}$ of $\mathrm {2\times}$ Lowry concentrate to each and every test tube including reference buffer, mix thoroughly, incubate at room temperature for $\pu {10 min}$.
Add $\pu {200 \mu L}$ of $\mathrm {0.2N}$ Folin reagent very quickly, and vortex immediately. Complete mixing of the reagent must be accomplished quickly to avoid decomposition of the reagent before it reacts with protein. Incubate for $\pu {30 min}$ more at room temperature (Final volume: $\pu {1.0 mL}$).
Use glass or polystyrene cuvettes (pathlength: $\pu {1cm}$) to read the absorbance at $\pu {750 nm}$. If the absorbance is too high, they may be read at $\pu {500 nm}$.

**Comments:** Recording of absorbance needs only to be done within $\pu {10 min}$ of each other for this modified procedure whereas the original Lowry required precise timing of readings due to color instability. This modification is less sensitive to interfering agents and is more sensitive to protein than the original. As with most assays, the modified Lowry assay can be scaled up for larger cuvette sizes, however more protein will be consumed. Be aware that proteins with an abnormally high or low percentage of tyrosine, tryptophan, or cysteine residues will give high or low errors, respectively.

**References:**

[1] Protein measurements with the Folin phenol reagent: Oliver H. Lowry,  Nira J. Rosebrough, A. Lewis Farr, Rose J. Randall, *Journal of Biological Chemistry*, **1951**, *193*, 265-275 (http://www.jbc.org/content/193/1/265.full.pdf).

[2] Hartree-Lowry and Modified Lowry Protein Assays by Reformed University Fellowship (http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~bioslabs/methods/protein/lowry.html)

[3] Measurement of protein using bicinchoninic acid: P. K. Smith, R. I. Krohn, G. T. Hermanson, A. K. Mallia, F. H. Gartner, M. D. Provenzano, E. K. Fujimoto, N. M. Goeke, B. J. Olson, D. C. Klenk,  *Analytical Biochem.*, **1985**, *150(1)*, 76–85 (doi:10.1016/0003-2697(85)90442-7).

[4] Chapter 6. Quantitation of Protein: Christa M. Stoscheck, In *Methods in Enzymology*; Murray P. Deutscher, Ed., **1990**, *182*, 50-68 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0076-6879(90)82008-P).

[5] Determination of protein: A modification of the lowry method that gives a linear photometric response: E. F. Hartree, *Analytical Biochem.*, **1972**, *48(2)*, 442–427 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-2697(72)90094-2).

[6] Optimization of Folin-Ciocalteu reagent concentration in an automated Lowry protein assay: G. M. Oosta, , N. S. Mathewson, and G. N. Catravas, *Analytical Biochem.*, **1978**, *89(1)*, 31–34 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-2697(78)90723-6).